# JQuery Flickr API

Tags: jquery, concurrency, flickr, image-preloader

I am writing a script using jQuery and Flickr REST API.

following the the pseudo algo

1) Hit Flickr API and get a list of photos using `$.getJSON` nad create `li` list elements:

```
create_gallery: function(){
    $.getJSON(
        $.prep_api_url(),
        function(data){
            $.each(data.photos.photo, function(i,item){
                var photo_raw_url = 
                    'http://farm' + item.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + 
                    item.server + '/' + item.id + '_' + item.secret;
                var photo_url = photo_raw_url + '_b.jpg';
                $('<li><a id="' + item.id + '" class="image_trigger" href=' + 
                   photo_url + '><img class="thumbnails" src=' + photo_raw_url +
                       '_s.jpg' + ' width=22 hight=22 /><a/>' +
                       '</li>').appendTo('.image_thumbs');
            });
            $('.thumbnails').css({'opacity' : '.6'});
        }
    );
},
```

2) Preload all the images by refferring created list **(I have Problems Here)**

3) On click of every image display the image from preloaded array

Now I want this

1) get the JSON object from Flickr

2) create the list and append it to DOM

3) after successfull insertion, run through all images from list and **preload** them **sequentially** one by one.

I have also tried async option, nothing happend

Comment: did you step through using Firebug? try pulling out that named function and throw a breakpoint in there. Does it enter? What are the values of the objects? Until you show me that you have stepped through it, I won't.

Comment: neways thanks for the thoughts though, I figured it out....

Comment: Please post your finnished code. @codemastersnake Would love to use seomthing like this.

Comment: Heyy Mattias, You can view the source at: http://www.neerajkumar.name/necromancer/ :)

Comment: Please answer your own question with the code and accept the answer. That way this question gets off the "unanswered" list, and people can find your solution without having to dig through comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used JS image object and load functions in a while loop to preload images before adding them to DOM.

you can find the result by viewing the source code at: http://www.neerajkumar.name/necromancer/